# Should I capitalize button text when quoting it?

Tags: grammar

If I'm quoting a button that's capitalized, should I also capitalize it in a sentence? For example, if the button is "Next," should it be:

Click "Next" to move on. 
OR 
Click "next" to move on.

Comment: Yes, you would capitalize it - if you even need the text at all.

Answer (score 5):

If you feel the need to explain your UI, there might be something wrong with it.

The classic joke applies here - A UI is like a joke. If you have to explain it, it isn’t very good.

People generally understand how to use ‘Next’ buttons to move through a process.

You might perhaps focus on the size, location, and clarity of your button, rather than how to instruct users in its use.

If you insist on this line of instructional copy, refer to the actual name of the button i.e. ‘Next’. Match the case.

Also, in referring to names or titles, the use of single quotes is common, appropriate, and is a less heavy punctuation mark.  Save double quotes for actual quotations.

Comment: For the Next text, italics might be even more appropriate than quotation marks. I agree, though, that it's best to avoid such messages altogether.

Comment: @TinMan - Given how easy elaboate typesetting has become, both for paper/pdf and web, I might even opt for making it look like an actual button, rather than setting it off with quotes or italic.

Answer (score 0):

Besides not being able to provide any research on that issue I suppose it's a common assumption that either all uppercase or lowercase texts generally not readable rather than the texts starting with capitalized letters.

I even realized it with your sample again while reading your question. Maybe the word "Next" is shorter but it's effect starting to be more severe as if the word's length increased comparingly.

> `Next                            next                               NEXT`
>
> `Indentation                  indentation                        INDENTATION`